# terraform output multiple aws ebs_volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

```
$ terraform --version
Terraform v0.11.7
+ provider.aws v1.28.0
```

I would like to find out if it's possible to output all the ebs volumes from an AWS instance.

I have a main.tf with the below:

```
data "aws_instance" "kafka_nodes" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["mykas00*"]
  }
}

output "block_devs" {
  value = "${data.aws_instance.kafka_nodes.ebs_block_device}"
}
```

The above only prints one volume but I have verified with `AWS CLI` that the instance in question has multiple volumes

Comment: data types like maps and lists can be exported like this
`
output "block_devs" {
  value = ["${data.aws_instance.*.ebs_block_device}"]
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only prints one volume because you have only set up one volume in the data source .  If you check the state file you'll probably see that it has only 1 device listed even though there are multiple devices connected.

You need to set up a data source for each volume.  But, that implies that you already know about the number of volumes.  So, that's probably not the way to go.

A way to get a list of all volumes attached to any given instance is to use the instance resource along with the  instance id, ami, and instance type.  Use **terraform import** to import the instance into state.  Then use **terraform refresh** to display all the volumes attached to the instance.

Change

```
data "aws_instance" "kafka_nodes" {
  filter {
    name = "tag:Name"
    values = ["mykas00*"]
  }
}

output "block_devs" {
  value = "${data.aws_instance.kafka_nodes.ebs_block_device}"
}
```

to

```
resource "aws_instance" "kafka_nodes" {
  ami = "<INSTANCE_AMI>"
  instance_type = "<INSTANCE_TYPE>"
  tags {
    Name = "mykas00"
  }
}

output "block_devs" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.kafka_nodes.ebs_block_device}"]
}
```

Add the below if you also want the root device listed

```
output "root_dev" {
  value = ["${aws_instance.kafka_nodes.root_block_device}"]
}
```

Then do

```
terraform import aws_instance.kafka_nodes [instance_id]    
terraform refresh
```

You should see a list of all devices connected to the instance similar to:

```
block_instance_devs = [
    {
        delete_on_termination = 0,
        device_name = /dev/sdc,
        encrypted = 0,
        iops = 100,
        snapshot_id = ,
        volume_id = vol-0ceea4f464a24d86a,
        volume_size = 8,
        volume_type = gp2
    },
    {
        delete_on_termination = 0,
        device_name = /dev/sdb,
        encrypted = 0,
        iops = 100,
        snapshot_id = ,
        volume_id = vol-0c0608cf0126f0b2b,
        volume_size = 8,
        volume_type = gp2
    },
    {
        delete_on_termination = 0,
        device_name = /dev/sdd,
        encrypted = 0,
        iops = 100,
        snapshot_id = ,
        volume_id = vol-0fe3c4c67bedf0e9e,
        volume_size = 8,
        volume_type = gp2
    }
]
```

AND even the root device if you added the section for it.

```
    root_dev = [
        {
            delete_on_termination = 1,
            iops = 100,
            volume_id = vol-0197cdd29d212c642,
            volume_size = 8,
            volume_type = gp2
        }
    ]
```